# Concatenating 3 multidimensional arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have three arrays `I1,I2,I3` with shape `(1,9,2)`. I am trying to append but there is an error. The new array should have shape `(3,9,2)`

```
import numpy as np

I1 = np.array([[[0, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 5],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 1],
        [4, 7],
        [5, 6],
        [6, 7]]])

I2 = np.array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 5],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 1],
        [4, 7],
        [5, 6],
        [6, 7]]])

I3 = np.array([[[2, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 5],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 1],
        [4, 7],
        [5, 6],
        [6, 7]]])

I=np.append(I1,I2,I3,axis=0)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    Iit=np.append(Iit1,Iit2,Iit3,axis=0)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in append

TypeError: _append_dispatcher() got multiple values for argument 'axis'
```

Comment: try : `np.concatenate((I1,I2,I3),axis=0)`

Comment: you didn't read the `append` docs with enough care!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `I=np.concatenate([I1,I2,I3],axis=0)` rather than `append`. Append does what you'd expect from a list (and try not to use it in numpy, anyway, for memory allocation reasons!)`

Answer (score 0):

A different way from @Dominik is

```py
I = np.stack((I1,I2,I3))
```

[stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) creates a new axis.